# Is it possible to use a ternary operator inside YAML with ERB, if so how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, erb

I've been trying many syntax variations on the below but cannot get anything other than a syntax error (the simple erb interpolation works on its own, but the logical ternary operator throws a syntax error):

```
start_prompt: "Drum roll please \U0001F941\U0001F941\U0001F941.
    <%= active_player_name %> will <%= @new_game ? "begin" : "continue" %> play.
    Let the game commence \U0001F3AC. And may the best player win \U0001F3C6."
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?
(I realise it'd be better practice to write such logic elsewhere, but a long story short  in this context it's just easier here and no matter how good or bad a practice this is, I'd like to know how/whether this is possible anyway. Thanks

Comment: I since find that using this; `start_prompt: |` with the pipe format has the embedded ERB logic working well, but then the emoji Unicode does not work with simply literal outputting of the code (i'm outputting this into the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

YAML doesn't support string interpolation in the same way that some other languages do.
You may need to pre-process your YAML file in a ruby script, and then write the processed content to the YAML file.

Here's an example:

```rb
active_player_name = "John Doe"
new_game = true

yaml_content = <<~YAML
start_prompt: "Drum roll please \\U0001F941\\U0001F941\\U0001F941.
    #{active_player_name} will #{new_game ? "begin" : "continue"} play.
    Let the game commence \\U0001F3AC. And may the best player win \\U0001F3C6."
YAML

File.open('output.yaml', 'w') { |file| file.write(yaml_content) }
```

Alternatively, you can modify/substitute the string from the yaml file dynamically based on the conditions

Comment: Thanks @chidi-ekuma. So if I understand your comment correctly you're saying that in order for string interpolation of the ternary logic (the simple variable interpolation does already work in my example) to work, or at least one way for it to work, I'd need to write this YAML data/string to a file object (of `.yaml` suffix), save it, then have my Ruby script read from the saved YAML file that it created and wrote to, as opposed to from my original YAML?

Comment: @jbk that's a potential solution, but I can see from your comment, that you've got the string interpolation working anyways. If that's the case then you're sorted.
That's probably a better solution an alternative is to ditch the yaml completely and use a multi line string and have variables in it and have the controller handle that